# redirecting results into file

Tags: python

I am using the script below to extract data from some trajectory file and dump the data into new files files. I can use directive ">"  to redirect results  into  a file but I need to do like this for more then 2000 files then. For make things easy I tried to open a file and let the python itself direct the results into a file.

To achieve  that  I added a line, at the place, (##) in the code, to open a file as shown below.
Also I added a line to direct the results into  a file as shown in the code below at line contains (###).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
always put -- #!/usr/bin/env python -- at the shebang
'''

from Scientific.IO.NetCDF import NetCDFFile as Dataset
import itertools as itx


inputfile = "../traj-waters/waters1445-MD001-run1000.traj"


for FRAMES in range(0,2):
   frame = FRAMES

   text_file = open("velo-Output.dat", "w")   (##)

   #inputfile = 'mdcrd'
   ppp = inputfile

   def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
       args = [iter(iterable)] * n
       return itx.izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

   formatxyz = "%12.7f%12.7f%12.7f%12.7f%12.7f%12.7f"
   formatxyz_size = 6
   formatxyzshort = "%12.7f%12.7f%12.7f"
   formatxyzshort_size = 3

   #ncfile = Dataset(inpitfile, 'r')
   ncfile = Dataset(ppp, 'r')

   variableNames = ncfile.variables.keys()
   #print variableNames

   shape = ncfile.variables['coordinates'].shape
   '''
   do the header
   '''

   print 'title ' + str(frame)
   print "%5i%15.7e" % (shape[1],ncfile.variables['time'][frame])


   '''
   do the velocities
   '''
   try:
       xyz = ncfile.variables['velocities'][frame]
       temp = grouper(2, xyz, "")

       for i in temp:
           z = tuple(itx.chain(*i))
           if (len(z) == formatxyz_size): 
               print formatxyz % z
               text_file.write('formatxyz\n' % z))  (###)
           elif (len(z) == formatxyzshort_size): print formatxyzshort % z


   except(KeyError):

       xyz = [0] * shape[2] 
       xyz = [xyz] * shape[1]
       temp = grouper(2, xyz, "")

       for i in temp:
           z = tuple(itx.chain(*i))
           if (len(z) == formatxyz_size): print formatxyz % z
           elif (len(z) == formatxyzshort_size): print formatxyzshort % z
           x = ncfile.variables['cell_angles'][frame]
           y = ncfile.variables['cell_lengths'][frame]
   text_file.close()
```

But I get error if I run this code as below.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./Nctorst-onlyVelo.py", line 73, in <module>
  text_file.write(str('formatxyz\n' % z))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Since I am newbie into python I find lost to correct this issue.

Advance thanks for help.
Regards

Comment: You're not actually using `z` in the string...

Comment: Thanks for the indication. It is working now. Additionally I changed text_file = open("velo-Output.dat", "w") to   text_file = open("velo-Output.dat", "a") so that in the next loop the data is append to the follwoing line. But this does't happen. The new data start from the same line (from end word of last line). How I can make the proceeding data get written in the file with new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you made a Typo, or did not understand how [string formating with replacement operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)  works

The Line

```
text_file.write('formatxyz\n' % z))  (###)
```

Should be written similar to the previous line

```
text_file.write(formatxyz % z + '\n')  (###)
```

Also you should look forward to use the [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

`print formatxyz % z`  <-- here it is modulo operator

`text_file.write('formatxyz\n' % z))`  (###)  <--- here is string replacement. Do not use

`formatxyz\n'` 
as a string.

Instead do this :

```
 text_file.write(str(formatxyz % z ) + '\n' )
```

Example showing the difference between the two :

```
>>> formatxyz = 97
>>> z = 10
>>> formatxyz % z
7
>>> 'formatxyz' % z
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
>>> x = 'Hello world'
>>> 'formatxyz is %s' % x
'formatxyz is Hello world'
```